# Upgrade old laptop RAM

Tags: memory, ddr3

The old laptop is T400, with motherboard type: Interl GM45, CPU:Intel P8700

Now I have 2*2GB(1066MHZ) RAM inserted in slots, but I am consider to upgrade to 2*4GB RAM, since the Maximum Memory per slot : 4GB

However, I also consider to purchase a new laptop, and I will upgrade my laptop to 2*8GB (1600MHZ) DDR3L.

So can I buy 2*8GB (1600MHZ) DDR3L RAM kit, and insert a 8GB 1600 DDR3L into a maximum 4GB supported RAM slot?

Comment: No. If it supports a maximum of 4GB per slot, it does not support 8GB per slot.

Comment: If you just really wanted to try it though, it won't hurt your computer to try it. Worst case scenario your laptop just won't recognize it.

Comment: @jAce Is it possible that I insert 8GB RAM, and only use its 4GB size?

Comment: As far as I know it's either going to recognize the 8gb's or none at all. I don't think a computer can split a stick and choose to only use part of it. Someone can correct me though if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I've many several machines over the years be able to support more RAM than the manufacture's limit, it is not advisable since it typically means that they didn't test it during manufacturing.

I'd highly recommend not upgrading beyond the official limits.